# .homestead nor Homestead.yaml is showing up after running bash init.bat

Tags: windows, laravel, homestead

I got homestead folder from git bash using `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`  into Documents folder.When I cd into Homestead folder and when I run `bash init.bat` this is what it shows up and it won't create `.homestead` folder

```
$ bash init.bat;
init.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
init.bat: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
init.bat: line 3: `if ["%~1"]==["json"] ('
```

if i run `bash init.sh` it shows:

```
$ bash init.sh;
cp: cannot stat 'src/stubs/Homestead.yaml': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'src/stubs/after.sh': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'src/stubs/aliases': No such file or directory
Homestead initialized!
```

but no `.homestead` folder or `Homestead.yaml` shows up

Answer (score 4):

Don't run that in git bash.  Run it in Windows' command line.  Or better yet just double click `init.bat` and it will run it for you relative to your Windows home directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you tried it through powershell instead of cmd. Try **CTRL+R -> cmd -> init.bat**